# Test 80,000+ simulated normal distribution observation sets against a null hypothesis

Tags: python, simulation, gaussian, hypothesis-test

I need to generate a random sample of size 200 (n=200) from a normal distribution with variance 1 and true mu (average) I specify; then, I test the draw against a hypothesis: mu <= 1. I need to do this for each of 400 potential true thetas, and for each true theta I need to replicate this 200 times.

I already did this for n=1, but I realize my approach is not replicable. For each 400 thetas, I ran the following:

```
sample_r200n1_t2=normal(loc=-0.99, scale=1, size=200)
sample_r200n1_t3=normal(loc=-0.98, scale=1, size=200)
sample_r200n1_t4=normal(loc=-0.97, scale=1, size=200)
sample_r200n1_t5=normal(loc=-0.96, scale=1, size=200)
... on and on to loc = 3
```

Then, I tested each element in the generated array separately. However, that approach would require me to generate tens of thousands of samples, I generate the mean associated with each, then test that mean against my criteria. This would have to be done 80,000 times (and, on top of this I need to do this for multiple different sizes n). Clearly - this is not the approach to take.

How can I achieve the results I am looking for? Is there a way, for example, to generate an array of sample means and put those means into an array, one per theta? Then I could test as before. Or, is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate all `200*200*400 = 16 million` random values in a numpy array (which consumes ~122 megabytes of memory; check with `draws.nbytes/1024/1024`), and use SciPy to run a one-sided, one-sample t-test on each of the 200 samples of 200 observations for each value of theta:

```
from numpy.random import normal
from scipy.stats import ttest_1samp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Array of loc values; for each loc, we draw 200 
# samples of 200 normally distributed observations
locs = np.linspace(-1, 3, 401)

# Array of shape (401, 200, 200) = (locs, samples, observations)
# Note that 200 draws of 200 i.i.d. observations is the same as
# 1 draw of 200*200 i.i.d. observations, reshaped to (200, 200)
draws = np.array([normal(loc=x, scale=1, size=200*200)
                  for x in locs]).reshape(401, 200, 200)

# axis=1 computes t-test across columns.
# Alternative hypothesis that sample mean
# is less than the population mean of 1 implies a null
# hypothesis that sample mean is greater than or equal to
# the population mean
tstats, pvals = ttest_1samp(draws, 1, alternative='less', axis=1)

# Count how many out of 200 t-tests reject the null hypothesis
# at the alpha=0.05 level
rejects = (pvals < 0.05).sum(axis=1)

# Visual check: p-values should be low for sample means
# far below 1, as these tests should reject the null 
# hypothesis that sample mean >= 1
plt.plot(locs, rejects)
plt.axvline(1, c='r')
plt.title('Number of t-tests rejecting $H_0 : \mu \geq 1$ with $p < 0.05$')
plt.xlabel('Known sample mean $\\theta$')
```

[image: plot of rejected null hypotheses versus theta]

Comment: Thank you, this is super helpful! Just a Q - for example, one task is to draw 200 random samples each of size 200 from a normal distribution with one of the thetas. Using this approach, I take it I would run that code 200 times? Just want to make sure I am interpreting this properly

Comment: This code draws 200 random samples for each value of theta, where theta takes on 401 values: -1, -0.99, -0.98, ..., 2.98, 2.99, 3. So no need to re-run this code multiple times. The result is a 2-dimensional numpy array which I named `draws`. This array has 401 rows and 200 columns. Each row contains the 200 random normal values for that row's corresponding value of theta.

Comment: Apologies - per theta I am trying to draw 200 random samples, where each sample contains 200 observations. It seems like this draws 200 i.i.d. observations per value of theta - aka, one random sample of 200 observations. Or am I confused? It seems that each row is a theta, and each column is an iid observation? In an ideal world, the value in each column would be a mean associated with a random IID draw of 200 observations

Comment: Oh I see - your understanding of my current answer is correct. After drawing 200 samples of 200 observations each for each value of theta, how would you need to run your t-tests?

Comment: I'm supposed to run the t-test on each sample. So, find the mean of each sample and test it against the null hypothesis. Then, compare outcomes at different levels of n (what % of tests accepted vs rejected the null at different levels of true theta / different levels of n)

Comment: Ok, I think I understand now! I've updated my answer to count how many of the 200 t-tests reject the null hypothesis at the 0.05 level for each value of theta. Hope that's closer to your needs

Comment: Great to hear! Probably a good idea to double-check my statistics :)